# Android: how do I increment SQLite INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT Column?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-edittext

In my activity I have a Save button that upon clicking will save a bunch of user input data to a SQLite table.  On the same click, I want to also increment an integer counter in another table.  The counter is set up as "cardnum".

What am I missing here?

**Activity file:**

```
...
public void onClickSave(View v) {

    helper = new DatabaseHelper(CardViewActivity.this);
    helper.insertIntoTableTOTALCOUNT();
    ...
    startActivity(new Intent(CardViewActivity.this,ListActivity.class));
}
```

**DBContract.java**

```
public final class DBContract {
    public DBContract() {}

    public static abstract class DBEntry implements BaseColumns {

        // Strings for USERINPUTS TABLE
        public static final String TABLE_NAME_USERINPUTS = "userinputs";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ID = "_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TODO = "todo";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_NOTE1 = "note1";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_NOTE2 = "note2";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_DUEDATE = "duedate";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_DUETIME = "duetime";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";

        // Strings for COUNT TABLE
        public static final String TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT = "totalcount";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNTID = "count_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM = "cardnum";
    }
}
```

**DBHelper file:**

```
...
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // Set up the Column headings in USERINPUTS TABLE
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
    // Set up the Column headings in TOTALCOUNT TABLE
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_COUNTER);
    // Put a default zero value in the CARDNUM counter to get started.
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT +
          "(count_id," + DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM+") VALUES (1,0)");
}

private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_NAME_USERINPUTS +
            "(" + DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ID +
                  " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TODO +
                  " TEXT,"
                + DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NOTE1 +
                  " TEXT,"
                + DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NOTE2 +
                  " TEXT,"
                + DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DUEDATE +
                  " TEXT,"
                + DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DUETIME +
                  " TEXT,"
                + DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TIMESTAMP +
                  " INTEGER" + ")";

private static final String SQL_CREATE_COUNTER =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT +
            "(" + DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_COUNTID+
                  " INTEGER UNIQUE, "
                + DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM +
                  " INTEGER" + ")";

    public void insertIntoTableTOTALCOUNT() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.beginTransaction();

    db.execSQL(INCREMENT_COUNT1);
    db.execSQL(INCREMENT_COUNT2);

    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
    // Close the DB
    if(db.isOpen())
    db.close();
}

public static final String INCREMENT_COUNT1 = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO "+ DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT+
        " (count_id,"+DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM+") VALUES (1,0)";
public static final String INCREMENT_COUNT2 = "UPDATE " + DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT+" SET "+ DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM + "="+ DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM+"+1";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the thing seems weird to me because the value you want to increase is equal to the number of records in your other table which can be get with a simple `"COUNT"` query but here you can achieve this:

First change your count table description to:

```
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_NAME_COUNT +
        "(_id INTEGER UNIQUE, " + DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM +
              " INTEGER" + ")"
```

in your onCreate in SqliteOpenHelper initialize the counter to 0:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+ DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_NAME_COUNT + 
           "(_id," + DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM+") VALUES (1,0)");
```

Add a final String to your class:

```
public static final String INCREMENT_COUNT1 = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO "+ DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_NAME_COUNT+
" (_id,"+DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM+") VALUES (1,0)";
public static final String INCREMENT_COUNT2 = "UPDATE " + DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_NAME_COUNT+" SET "+ DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM + "=" + DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM+"+1";
```

Change the following function:

```
public void insertIntoTableCount() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL(INCREMENT_COUNT1);
    db.execSQL(INCREMENT_COUNT2);
    db.close();
}
```

in your `onClickSave` do the following:

```
helper = new DatabaseHelper(CardViewActivity.this);

//for extra caution it is better to add beginTransaction here
helper.insertIntoTableUserInputs(todo,note1,note2,duedate,duetime,timestamp);
helper.insertIntoTableCount();
//add setTransactionSuccessfull() and endTransaction here
```

Comment: The user will be able to delete data from the first table which would reduce the count.  That is why I set up a second table so that I can keep a running count even if records are deleted from the first table. If I don't need a second table to do this, please advise on how I would do this on the first table.  My goal was to keep a running count of the number of records created, even if they were deleted later.

Comment: @AJW for the first table if you have an ID with AUTOINCREMENT value, then even if you add a new record the ID will be incremented and hold the number of records you have inserted in that table

Comment: Yes but if the user later deletes a record then the ID will be decremented.  I want the total numbers of records ever created.  Please advise.

Comment: @AJW no with the AUTOINCREMENT it won't be decremented

Comment: Ok.  I don't understand though.  If the user creates 5 records then the ID for each will be 1,2,3,4 and 5.  If the user deletes the 5th record then only the four remain: 1,2,3 and 4 and the 4th record would have an ID of 4.  If the user then creates a new record I want it to be ID #6, which would be 1 plus the total number of records ever created of 5 = 6.

Comment: @AJW OK I understood your point and you are right this method doesn't work if the user deletes the last element. There is alternative way, instead of deleting records from the table, just add another column ('status' for example) and on insert put 'true' and on delete put 'false' in this way no records will be deleted and still you can use 'count()' but you need to make a change for getting query to just query the results where status=true

Comment: Ok, nice idea.  So after creating say hundreds of records would my approach to create a second table with a single column be faster and more efficient or would your new approach using status be better?

Comment: @AJW I personally prefer the second approach because the first needs two execution of SQL bound in a transaction for data consistency and also with the first one you can keep track of the deleted records too

Comment: I understand.  Do I run the risk of the database becoming too big over time though because no records ever get deleted?  I am developing the app for mobile devices so database size I think would eventually become a constraining factor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110760/discussion-between-pooya-and-ajw).

Comment: The String "INCREMENT_COUNT" is crashing the app with the following message: "SQLiteException: near "ON": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO totalcount (cardnum) VALUES (0) ON DUPLICATE cardnum=cardnum+1"  Any ideas here?

Comment: Android Studio won't accept "DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM+"="DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM+"+1";" Should the code have a "+" after the "="?  So it would read:  "DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM+"="+DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM+"+1";"

Comment: @AJW I made a change to the queries and also the function. see the updated answer and let me know if it works

Comment: Ok I'm trying now.

Comment: Android Studio message: "Variable expected" on the INCREMENT_COUNT2 code.

Comment: @AJW sorry it was a syntax error from my side, Please check INCREMENT_COUNT2 again

Comment: Ok I see it now.  Also, looks like I need a + after "=".  Yes?

Comment: @AJW yes that's correct sorry I'm on mobile now and it's hard to see the syntax outlines

Comment: Ok looking better and better.  I hope I have just one more issue to solve.  App crashes with message that table has no column named count_id.  A few variables have slightly different names now versus what I posted above yesterday.  Do you recommend to update everything above?

Comment: @AJW try to uninstall your app first and then re-install it it may fixes some name conflicts

Comment: Ok will try.  Also INCREMENT_COUNT1 says initially set default values of 1 and 0.  Then next time ignore the values because they were previously set and INCREMENT_COUNT2 will run to update the counter column CARDNUM by +1?

Comment: Just need to solve the mystery around crash with message that TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT has no column named "count_id".  I will update code above.  I uninstalled and cleaned project and rebuilt so I don't know what is happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111334/discussion-between-pooya-and-ajw).

Answer (score 0):

I think it does not make sense , a table with single column and define as primary key.

If you have a table with primary key : for example, table name Student and columns are studentid, studenName. studentid declared as primary key and autoincrement then you need to only insert record in studentName column as follows :

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values2 = new ContentValues();
    values2.put("studentName", studentName);

    db.insert("Student", null, values2);
```

Internally this query will be

```
INSERT INTO Student (studentid,studenName)
VALUES (null,studentname);
```

Primary key and auto-incremented value passed as null so that sqlite engine identify that it is a autoincrement column and row value auto-incremented by 1.

Comment: The user will be able to delete data from the first table.  That is why I set up a second table so that I can keep a running count even if records are deleted from the first table.  If I don't need a second table to do this, please advise on how I would do this on the first table.

Comment: In thinking more about this I would like to create the second table with a single column and a single row.  The title of the column would be "TotalCount".  The single row would be the cumulative number of records ever created by the user.  In other words a total count of the number of records created, even if the corresponding records were deleted in the first table.  Basically I'm looking for an object that holds a total count.  It starts at 1 and is incremented by +1 every time a new record is created, when the "Save" button is clicked.  Thoughts?